# Can the new is pattern match syntax work with existing variables?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

I have existing code:

```
    internal bool firstAsSymbol(out Symbol s)
    {
        return (s = first as Symbol) != null;
    }
```

I can use the new `is` syntax, but I need to introduce local variables:

```
    internal bool firstAsSymbol(out Symbol s)
    {
        var result = first is Symbol sym;
        s = sym;
        return result;
    }
```

EDIT: In fact, the above code doesn't compile! `sym` may be undefined on the `s = sym;` line. So it's even worse: you have to use an `if` statement and assign `s` in both the then and else clause. (It does try to allow `sym` to be valid to touch in the right clause).

Is there any simpler alternative (other than the original code, of course)?

Comment: Why do you even have the method in the first place? How is it useful?

Comment: The code was originally written to avoid casting at the calling site, so I need to return the casted value.

Comment: This is a good refactor pattern to reduce the complexity of the calling code, nothing wrong with this as a method

Comment: @CallumLinington Yes, that's what it was trying to do. I think a possible answer is to go to calling sites and just change the call to `first is Symbol outvar`.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary This is in a `Cons` class, with a `first` (`car`) and `rest` (`cdr`).

Comment: I got your point. your first method looks fine. seems cant get better ^.*

Comment: I would be tempted to change the name from `firstAsSymbol` to `TryGetFirst`, firstly it follows the microsoft pattern of `Try[Name]` where it will return bool if successful and the actual value. Secondly it doesn't need `Symbol` because the params and the container class should be single responsibility (e.g. working with Symbols)

Comment: I've added VSFeedback re the EDIT: [pattern match fails to produce a useful local variable](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/10892/pattern-match-fails-to-produce-a-useful-local-vari.html "The code displays OK in the VSFeedback app :-(")

Answer (score 2):

As you have discovered, variables introduced via an `is T` expression end up in scope after the expression line, but are unusable as they may not be assigned.

The reasons behind this are due to the new `out var` feature. To make that feature work the way they wanted, the language team have allowed `out var` variables to leak out into surrounding scope. They then made the decision to allow `is T` variables to leak in the same way, even though they can't be used in that outer scope, as they may not be assigned.

I wrote an article on this sorry state of affairs recently: [C# 7, “out var” and changing variable scope](https://web.archive.org/web/20190827124606/http://www.davidarno.org/2016/11/23/c-7-and-out-var-or-how-to-seriously-screw-up-a-language/).

As for how you could rewrite the code to take advantage of C# 7 features, one way is to use a tuple:

```cs
internal (bool, Symbol) FirstAsSymbol() =>
    first is Symbol sym ? (true, sym) : (false, null);
```

But really, it would be worth looking at the code that calls `FirstAsSymbol` to see whether *that* could make better use of the new features.

Answer (score 1):

As I realised in the comment to the question, it seems the calling site:

```
exprs.firstAsSymbol(out var s)
```

can be changed to:

```
exprs.first is Symbol s
```

EDIT: Except for the issue I noted in the question's edit: you can't assume `s == null` when the pattern match fails.

In hindsight, the routine should have been called `firstIsSymbol` :-)

Comment: I should add, this is only a solution for this specific case. I'd still like a solution for an `out` parameter whose value is defined by the result of a pattern match, but I'm guessing it's too late in the process for Microsoft to cater for that scenario.